# Does the Aharonov-Bohm effect change the phase of all wavefunctions in the Universe?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, wavefunction

In the double slit experiment with electrons, the interferential pattern on the screen is shifted in the presence of a long thin coil (through which of a current flows, Naturally) between the double slit plane and the projection screen, as well as between the slits: the    [Aharonov–Bohm effect](https://Aharonov%E2%80%93Bohm.com). The **A**-field (with zero **B**-field) changes the phases of the electron wavefunctions.

The magnitude of **A** diminishes with its distance to the coil but does it nevertheless change the phase instantly (non-locality) of all other wavefunctions (the farther away the wavefunction is from the coil, the lesser the change in its phase)? To put it differently: if the current in the coil is turned on, are all the wavefunctions in the Universe more or less (literally) influenced after some time?

Comment: Why do you think that the phase changes non-locally? The vector potential obeys the wave equation and changes propagate at the speed of light. -1.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty-You're right about that! I was confused by the non-local Nature of the change in the interference pattern. All the phases change at once. But that doesn't alter the core of my question. I changed my question.;-)

Comment: Since nothing in the derivation of the A-B effect uses a small distance approximation or anything, the distance to the coil obviously doesn't matter. Is there something more to this question? (If you are after some sort of communication scheme via the A-B effect, note that you must "close the loop" around the solenoid in order to detect it)

Comment: The question's premise is still incorrect, and you have yet to address my previous comment. The vector potential does *not* change instantly, nor does it do so non-locally.

Answer (score 0):

> if the current in the coil is turned on, are all the wavefunctions in the Universe more or less (literally) influenced after some time?

In principle, yes. However, unless those systems loop around the solenoid, the phase imparted by the system's interaction with the solenoid is exclusively a global phase so far as the system can tell, so it is completely undetectable by any possible experiment.

Put another way: yes, but not in any interesting, relevant, or physically measurable way.